# How to Adjust view for all screens in Xcode (Storyboard)?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, autolayout, storyboard

I'm a android developer new on IOS development.

I'm trying to make a screen for all device using single story board(h:any w:any).
I'm facing a issue when i try to create a prototype cell for all screen the prototype cell is invisible from right side of screen.
I have try to apply tailing space,leading space,horizontal spacing found not getting any solution.

Help me how can i fix this issue.

[image]Here is SS

Answer (score 1):

You could set following constraints for Right UImageView/UIButton

Select right Object

1.Align ->Vertically in container

[image]1.

2.Pin -> Uncheck Right edge to container(Trailing). and

[image]

3.Set Width and Height.

[image]

Or Another way is:

> 1. Pin -> Select Top,Right,Bottom
> 2. Pin -> Select With(ex.Fixed 40px)

Or

> 1.Pin -> Top, Right
>
> 2.Pin -> Height,Width.

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

You should use size classes to make your UI suitable for all form factors. Please go through the official document from Apple.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_adaptive_sizes/chapters/AboutAdaptiveSizeDesign.html

Alos you should use autolayout to put different constraints.